# Deleting files older than x years with vb6

Tags: vb6, datediff

I want to know how I can delete files older than x years

Note: my date is`mydate(yyyy/mm/dd)` i dont know if this can cause any problems or not

This is my code so far:

```
Dim fso As Variant
Dim directory As Variant
Dim modified As Variant
Dim files As Variant

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Set fso = CreateObject(“Scripting.FileSystemObject”)
    Set directory = fso.GetFolder(App.Path & "\log")
    Set files = directory.files

    For Each modified In files

    If DateDiff("Y", modified.DateLastModified, Now) > mydate Then

        modified.Delete

    Next

End Sub
```

I am using DateDiff for the first time in my life so please be kind on explaining where I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) returns the difference between two dates. You are using it to get the difference in years between the current date and when the file was last modified which is correct but you are then comparing this to a date variable (I think - you haven't included the definition of myDate). You need something more like:

```
If DateDiff("Y", modified.DateLastModified, Now) > x Then
    modified.Delete
End If
```

Where *x* is an integer number (*2* for files older than two years for example).

Comment: ahhh crap i dont believe i did such a mistake! its so crappy i guess its because i ve been sick enough to get a brain damage couldnt think right on this anyways thank you.

Comment: Also note that `DateDiff("Y"...)` gives only the difference in years values. The difference between 31/12/2011 and 1/1/2012 will give 1 year different despite only a 1 day difference.

Comment: You might want to consider changing the code so that DateDiff returns the difference in days rather than years to avoid the issue that @Deanna has raised.